# Stable Marriage algorithms other than Gale-Shapely?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

I've looked around lot and I haven't been able to find any algorithms for to the traditional stable marriage problem (I'm not talking about any of its variants like the roommate problem) besides the Gale-Shapely one. Is that because there's simply been no reason for trying to find another one, or is a completely different algorithm not been found despite research, or have I just missed the ones that exist?

Sorry for not including this initially. For those who're unfamiliar with the stable marriage problem here it is in its simplest form from good old wikipedia:

> Given n men and n women, where each person has ranked all members of the opposite sex in order of preference, marry the men and women together such that there are no two people of opposite sex who would both rather have each other than their current partners. When there are no such pairs of people, the set of marriages is deemed stable.

In other words, an unstable matching is one which contains members of the oposite sex who have not been married but simulatnously prefere each other to their assigned spouse.

Comment: It would be very helpful for you to include here in the question some information on the problems you reference (restate them, mathematically, so that your problem is self-contained).

Comment: Deferred acceptance is simple, works well and it is easy to explain. Why bother to find something different?

Comment: @SergioParreiras just curiosity should be enough, but from a practical standpoint, because the deferred acceptence algorithm has the disadvantage of always being optimal for one side and pessimal for the other and the further disadvantage of being gamable by the side being proposed to (traditionally the women)

Comment: You flip the groups and you have the best match for the women. The set of stable matches is a lattice. I am not an specialist but I imagine that with simple tweaks you should be able to get any stable matching.

Comment: Consider the set of all possible matchings, discard all the unstable ones, and pick at random one of the remaining matchings.

Comment: @hardmath you're technically right, but your algorithm runs in factorial time and it's brute forcing the problem. It works but it's a trivial solution. I'm looking to see if anyone has designed, or somehow proven it fundemetally impossible to design, an algorithm that solves the problem in some kind of practical time apart from Gale Shapley.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change the question? Which simple algorithms can I use to get stable matches that are not the ones picked by Gale--Shapley.